# Why does sub query does not create duplicate results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know how using joins can create duplicate values. Therefore we need to use the DISTINCT keyword with join statements. But why does using sub queries not give duplicate values as well? Consider the following to T-SQL statements that produces the same result

**Subquery**

```
 select ID, Name, Description
    from tblProducts
    where ID IN
    (
      Select ProductId from tblProductSales
    )
```

**Join**

```
 Select distinct tblProducts.Id, Name, Description
    from tblProducts
    inner join tblProductSales
    on tblProducts.Id= tblProductSales.ProductId
```

We have to use the distinct keyword for table joins but not for sub queries. I do not understand why is that

Comment: A`WHERE` can *never* introduce new rows; it can only *restrict* rows from the set it is being applied to.

Comment: A `JOIN`, *can* introduce new rows *when* the join multiplicity is > 1 - this means than the column(s) joined are not distinct in both joined sets and there is *duplicates* of the joined column(s) in one or the other sources; if the joined column(s) were already unique in both sources the multiplicity could not exceed 1. Only a JOIN with multiplicity > 1 can introduce additional rows.

Comment: I am sorry. What does "Introduce new row" mean?

Comment: tblProducts ahve multiple rows for same id

Answer (score 0):

On the first query, you scan products table and check if that product is on any sale. There for because each products appears only once no duplicated. `IN`is a boolean operator so even when the subquery return duplicate result only return a row if match any of those values.

On the second query you join each product with any sales matching the id. There for because same product have several sales you end with duplicates.

Join create a cartesian product between both tables.

Example:

```
 Pruducts       Sales
    1             1
    2             1
    3             2
                  2
                  2
```

First query return `(1,2)`

Second query resturn `(1,1,2,2,2)` because each row in products try to match with a rows in sales

Comment: Isn't the sub query always scanned first. So tblProductSales will be scanned first. Now if there are 3 product sales for let's say ID 1.  Then the sub query should return 1,1,1. Sholudn't tht main query return 3 duplicates values?

Comment: Nop. As I explain on the first query the main query check each row. If satiface the `WHERE` condition then return the row. if `ProductID`appear on the subset then the row is returned once even if match several times. That is what `IN` operator does. You are checking the row to see if is valid or not. On the second query you are doing a cartasian product.creatign a row for each match

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding `WHERE`s and `JOIN`s.

The first query does not produce duplicate results for a very simple reason.  The `WHERE` clause filters rows out of the result set or keeps them in.  That is all.  There is no possible "multiplication" of rows due to `WHERE` conditions.

Conceptually, you can think of `WHERE` procesing as:

- Read a row generated by the `FROM` clause.
- Apply the condition(s) in the `WHERE` clause.
- If the conditions evaluate to TRUE, then continue processing the row.
- If the conditions evaluate to FALSE or NULL, then remove the row.

The `JOIN` is a different beast entirely.  It is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause that combines two tables/derived tables.  Rows can be removed (when the `JOIN` conditions do not evaluate to TRUE).  Rows can be multiplied (when there are multiple matches).

Incidentally, the first approach is much better than the second.  `SELECT DISTINCT` incurs overhead -- even if all the rows are already distinct.  This is not needed for the second approach.

I would usually recommend writing this logic using `EXISTS`:

```
select p.ID, p.Name, p.Description
from tblProducts p
where exists (select 1
              from tblProductSales ps
              where ps.ProductId = p.ID
             );
```

I find that `EXISTS` is usually simpler to optimize, and `NOT EXISTS` is preferable to `NOT IN` because `NOT EXISTS` handles `NULL` values as you would expect (but that is another topic).